# get the last iteration in jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code that I am going through the tables columns and if its the last column I want it to do something different. Right now its hard coded but how can I change so it automatically knows its the last column

```
$(this).find('td').each(function (i) { 
    if(i > 0) //this one is fine..first column
    { 
        if(i < 4)  // hard coded..I want this to change 
        {
            storageVAR += $(this).find('.'+classTD).val()+',';
        }
        else
        {
            storageVAR += $(this).find('.'+classTD).val();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So, 'td' tags are used in every row, do you want the very last td, or the very last td in each row?

Comment: I came here from google looking for an answer to the title question, which is more generic than what the OP needed... So, how to know which one is the last iteration of $.each(something, function(...) {...}); when `something` is an object, instead of an array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want access to the length inside the `.each()` callback, then you just need to get the length beforehand so it's available in your scope.

```
var cells = $(this).find('td');
var length = cells.length;
cells.each(function(i) {
    // you can refer to length now
});
```

Comment: var total = $(this).find('td').length;

Comment: @Autolycus - but there's no point in recalculating all that when you need the selector for other uses - might as well save the jQuery object so you can use it more than once.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your objective is to make a comma separated list of the values, why don't you collect the values and use the array method 'join'?

```
var values = []
$(this).find('td .' + classTD).each(function(i) {
  if (i > 0) values.push($(this).val());
});
storageVAR = values.join(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
var $this = $(this),
    size  = $this.length,
    last_index = size -1;

$this.find('td').each(function (index) { 

     if(index == 0) { 
         // FIRST

     } else if(index === last_index) {
         // LAST

     } else {
         // ALL THE OTHERS

     }

});
```

Comment: Last would be `index === size-1`.

Answer (score -2):

If all you want is the last column, you can use

```
$(this).find('td:last')
```

If you want to do things with other columns, go for

```
$(this).find('td:last').addClass("last");
$(this).find('td').each(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass("last")) {
      // this is the last column
   } else {
      // this isn't the last column
   }
});
```

You can use `data()` instead of `addclass()` if you're comfortable with that.

If all you want to do is not have a comma at the end of your string, you could just chop it off afterward:

```
storageVAR = storageVAR.substr(0, (storageVAR.length - 1);
```